# Filter for triples in default graph (outside all named graphs) with SPARQL

Tags: sparql, knowledge-graph

In the below query I extract all entities with class `:Entity`, regardless of whether they live inside a specific context (named graph) or not.

```
SELECT ?s
WHERE {
    ?s a :Entity .
}
```

I would like to filter among these entities, to keep only those that don't live inside *any* named graph, i.e., only the entities that exist outside all named graphs (**EDIT:** I guess the correct terminology is that I want to search for triples only in the **default graph**).

How can I do this?

Comment: Try something like:
`SELECT ?s WHERE {?s a :Entity FILTER NOT EXISTS {GRAPH ?g {?s ?p ?o}}}`
If you also want `?s` to not exists as an object/predicate, then you can do a `UNION` inside the negation.

Comment: Awesome, this hadn't occurred to me. If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it without delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `FILTER NOT EXISTS` (see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-filter-exists)).

In particular, you are looking for resources (I assume IRIs) that exists in the default graph, but not in any named graphs.

So a query like this will work:

```
SELECT ?s
WHERE {
 ?s a :Entity
FILTER NOT EXISTS {
 GRAPH ?g {
  ?s ?p ?o 
  }
 }
}
```

This is saying that `?s` is not the subject of any triple in any named graph.
We can extend the query above to include the case where `?s` is not the *object* of any triple too:

```
SELECT ?s
WHERE {
 ?s a :Entity
FILTER NOT EXISTS {
 GRAPH ?g {
  {?s ?p ?o}
  UNION
  {?x ?p ?s}
   }
  }
}
```